# Single database transaction in Slick 3.1 with plain SQL updates

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm trying to run in Slick 3.1 a transaction that contains two updates. The second update is plain SQL using Slick's `sqlu` command. This is my attempt:

```
  val table = TableQuery[TableDB]
 
  val update1 = table.filter(f => f.name === name).update(rec)
  val update2 = sqlu"UPDATE table2 SET field = 1 WHERE field = 2"
  
  val action = (for {
          _ <- update1
          _ <- update2   // <-- compilation error here
        } yield ()).transactionally
  val future = db.run(action.asTry)
  // ... rest of the code
```

Slick complains in `update2` line with the following messages

> Implicit conversion found:  ⇒
> augmentString(): scala.collection.immutable.StringOps
>
> type mismatch; found : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Unit]
> required: slick.dbio.DBIOAction[?,?,?]

Is it possible to make this work in a single database transaction?

Comment: You sure about that? I just pasted it to my Slick sample project and it's not only compiling but even running fine (though obviously failing on SQL error as I don't have `table2`). Maybe something wrong with imports? Where does `sqlu` points to? It should point you to: `def sqlu(param: Any*): SqlAction[Int, NoStream, Effect] = macro sqluImpl`

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that Eclipse complained until I did a Rebuild All.